JS - Trying to draw on canvas by accessing sub object arrays
Firstly, some are gonna ask for a code dump, but I gotta tell ya, theres a lot of it and it has little to do with my question. I'm trying to draw on a canvas and each Class has its own draw method and all objects are created from a Class. Let me give you a rundown of my object structure....
object structure
In my Cell class (which is used to create the cells in each row) I have a draw method......how do I reference the x,y values of the cell.
    class Row {
        constructor(x,y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
    
            this.cells=[];
            this.addCells(this.x, this.y);                    
        }
        addCells(x,y) { 
            let cell_x = x + 24;
            for (let i=0;i<4;i++) {
                //y spacing is probably off
                this.cells.push(new Cell(cell_x,y + 10,15));
                cell_x +=40;
            }
        }
        draw(context) {
            //cells
            //console.log("row");
            //this.cells.forEach((i) => i.draw(context));            
        }
        update() {
    
        } }
class Cell {
    constructor(x,y,rad) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = rad;
        this.color;
    }
    draw(context) {
       // console.log(context);
        drawCircle(context,this.x, this.y, this.rad,"white"); 
        /*cells in a row            
        drawCircle(context,x_start, y_start+i*y_space, 15);           
        drawCircle(context,x_start+35, y_start+i*y_space, 15);            
        drawCircle(context,x_start+70, y_start+i*y_space, 15);            
        drawCircle(context,x_start+105, y_start+i*y_space, 15);
        
        //dividing line
        if (i<9) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(105,y_start+i*y_space+20);
            context.lineTo(255,y_start+i*y_space+20);
            context.stroke();
        }
        */
    }
    update() {

    }
}

The board.draw(context) calls row.draw(context) which calls
        //draw the rows
        this.rows.forEach((i) => i.draw(context));

And in my row.draw(context) method i have

        draw(context) {
        this.cells.forEach((i) => i.draw(context));
        

And in my cell.draw(context) method I have
console.log(this.x,this.y);
drawCircle(context,this.x, this.y, this.rad,"white"); 
//drawCircle is a global function that works fine

In my current Cell draw method I use this.x and this.y, but thats not working as console.log returns 0,0 for x,y, but the object structure shows cell[i].x and cell[i].y have proper values.
I'm not referencing x,y properly.
A little guidance here would be appreciated.
All the context calls before the cell.draw method work fine. I'm sure it's my x,y referencing I'm not geting right.

I'm afraid nobody in here is able to help you without seeing the class definition for Cell.
